# Django Offline Forms

Tags: python, django, forms, offline

I am looking to build a web-app that focuses on users submitting forms. Sometimes the users may be in a remote area with limited connection and I am looking for information on how the web app can hold the form submission until a network connection is established.

What packages or resources are available for this use-case?

Comment: You mean the state of the form (the response in other words) would be stored on the client side and then, sent when the users has remote connection ?